# How can I copy and paste a logo layer using Actions?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, actions

Is there a way to copy a layer from one file and paste it into multiple files using Actions? I already use actions to re-size the images, but I end up having to manually copy and paste the layer with our custom watermark.

I tried using the copy and paste in place to get the logo in correct position. Then I need to re-apply the styles to the layer - not an issue. I just need to select the same layer from the same file each time.

Comment: `File > Automate > Batch...` Should do this easily.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to use an action to place your logo in multiple files, but you can use the duplicate layer function in Photoshop

1. **Right-Click** the layer you want to duplicate.
2. Click on **"Duplicate layer..."**
3. **Select the Document** you want the logo to be transferred to.
4. Click **"Ok"** and the logo will be duplicated to the other file, it will also be on the same spot as the old one.

Hope this answer helped you out! Goodluck